# Cannot resolve method 'inflate' in 'DashboardActivity'

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

This is a simple application. I am using Intent to navigate from activity_main.xml to activity_dashboard.xml
In DashboardActivity.java file I am trying to use Data binding property. But I am getting 2 errors

1. Cannot resolve method 'inflate' in 'DashboardActivity'
2. Cannot resolve method 'getRoot' in 'DashboardActivity'

I have made changes in the build.gradle file. Also data binding is working fine in MainActivity.java but not in DashboardActivity.java

1. DashboardActivity.java

```
package com.example.inclasstask5;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.inclasstask5.databinding.ActivityDashboardBinding;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    TextView enteredData;

    DashboardActivity binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DashboardActivity.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view1 = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view1);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("login_Details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        enteredData = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        String username = sharedPref.getString("ID" , "No Username");
        enteredData.setText("Login Successfully - " + username);

    }

}
```

2. activity_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

1. sync the gradle files again
2. cleared caches

Comment: Did you follow the steps [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities)? Why aren't you using the binding class and inflating it?

Comment: binding declaration type should be ActivityDashboardBinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare binding variable as

```
ActivityDashboardBinding binding;
```

instead of

```
DashboardActivity binding;
```

And in activity's onCreate method assign

```
binding = ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
```

instead of

```
binding = DashboardActivity.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
```